# Parallel programming in Tensorflow code with Session.run

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, grpc

I am trying to implement distributed execution in my Tensorflow code. I created a simple example. When I run it, the program does not yield any result. My guess is the host locations are not set properly for my Linux system.

```
import tensorflow as tf


cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222", "localhost:2223"]})

x = tf.constant(2)


with tf.device("/job:local/task:1"):
    y2 = x - 66

with tf.device("/job:local/task:0"):
    y1 = x + 300
    y = y1 + y2


with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222") as sess:
    result = sess.run(y)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before running the session above, it is required to start 2 workers with another script (`python tfserver.py 0` & `python tfserver.py 1`). Additionally I had to replace `localhost` with the actual server name due to some restrictions in the cluster.

```
# Get task number from command line
import sys
task_number = int(sys.argv[1])

import tensorflow as tf

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222", "localhost:2223"]})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=task_number)

print("Starting server #{}".format(task_number))

server.start()
server.join()
```

Source: https://databricks.com/tensorflow/distributed-computing-with-tensorflow

More advanced usage here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/distributed.md